# What is the difference between ".*" and ".*?"

Tags: regex, tcl

I wanted to catch comment on code (everything from "--" to the end of the line) using regular expressions in TCL.

So I tried `{\\-\\-.*$}` that should be `-` then `-` then any number of any characters and then end of the line. But it doesn't work!

Another post here suggested using `.*?` instead of `.*`.

So I tried `{\\-\\-.*?$}` and that works.

Just wanted to understand the difference between the two. According to any regular expression tutorial/man I read the `?` condition should be a subset of `*`, so I am wondering what's going on there.

Comment: Could you please share a test case? Actually, `\-\-.*$` should produce the same result as `\-\-.*?$`

Comment: i think the title contains a typo `.*` or `.*?` the difference is greedy vs. lazy quantifiers, the first tries first to repeat then bactracks to following pattern, the second tries first the following pattern then backtracks to repeat

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not a problem description.

Comment: @user, you'll want to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok my fault, i was using \-\-[.]*$ and not \-\-.*$ wasn't aware taht the square brakets escape the . and make iterpreted as "the actual dot character" and not as "any char"

Comment: Here is a test case :

Comment: set tstCases {
{---------------} 
{--Un commentaire} 
{  toto<='1'; --un commentaire en ligne}
{  toto<=A - B; --un commentaire en ligne avec un piege}
{  toto<=A - B; --.}
}
set re1 {\-\-.*?$}
set re2 {\-\-.*$}
set re3 {\-\-[.]*$}
foreach case $tstCases {
    puts $case
    puts "re1catch :[regexp -all -inline $re1 $case]"
    puts "re2catch :[regexp -all -inline $re2 $case]"
    puts "re2catch :[regexp -all -inline $re3 $case]"
}

Comment: So yes they both effectively produce the same which is what i also expected. Makes me learn about the lazy search thing by the way so good to know. Thanks for all your feedback.

Comment: @melpomene the question is not about the exemple, i just say i happened to end up on a case where it indeed make a difference just to give a context. My question is about understanding the differences it makes in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"?" makes de previous quantifier lazy, making it match as few characters as posible.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the [re_syntax](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) man page. The question mark indicates the match should be non-greedy.

Let's look at an example:

```
% set string "-1234--ab-c-"
-1234--ab-c-
% regexp -inline -- {--.*-} $string
--ab-c-
% regexp -inline -- {--.*?-} $string
--ab-
```

The 1st match is greedy, matching to the *last* dash following  the double dash.
The 2nd match is not greedy, only matching to the *first* dash following  the double dash.

Note that the Tcl regex engine has a quirk: the **first** quantifier's greediness sets the greediness of the **whole regex**. This is documented (IMO obscurely) in the [MATCHING](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M95) section:

> ... A branch has the same preference as the first quantified atom in it which has a preference.

Let's try to match all the digits, the double dash, see how the non-greedy quantifiers work:

```
% regexp -inline -- {\d+--.*-} $string
1234--ab-c-
% regexp -inline -- {\d+--.*?-} $string
1234--ab-c-
```

Oops, the whole match is greedy, even though we asked for some non-greediness. 
To satisfy this criteria, either we need to make the first quantifier non-greedy as well:

```
% regexp -inline -- {\d+?--.*?-} $string
1234--ab-
```

or make all the quantifiers greedy and use a negated bracket expression:

```
% regexp -inline -- {\d+--[^-]*-} $string
1234--ab-
```

Comment: Curious voting pattern (currently 2 upvotes, 2 downvotes). Downvoters, care to comment?

Comment: I haven't voted, but I would suspect the downvotes are because you haven't actually addressed OP's case. Even if `?` does make the regex lazy, that still doesn't explain why `\\-\\-.*?$` produces a match and `\\-\\-.*$` doesn't, and your examples don't illuminate this either. As far as I can tell, both should be equivalent in behavior.

Comment: I suppose. I agree they should act the same. We're missing any feedback from the OP though.

Comment: well i do agree with you in my mind also it should produce the same, but it don't. My question is no so much on the particular exemple, i have one pattern that works so that project has lived it's life no problem. I just try to figure out the why because that makes me curious.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example string where the lazy regex matches but the greedy one does not.